# How to remove trailing spaces like characters in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, character, special-characters, trim

I have written a simple select query to select a single row from a table using a field named “Name”. The Names are sequential and presented as ‘RM001’, ‘RM002’, ‘RM003’…. This issue was that it didn’t pick up ‘RM004’ with the following query

```
-- Trim Name Field
UPDATE [dbo].[RoutineMaintenanceTask] SET  = LTRIM(RTRIM([dbo].[RoutineMaintenanceTask].Name));

-- Select the record
SELECT   *
FROM     [dbo].[RoutineMaintenanceTask]
WHERE    Name = 'RM004'
```

[image]

When I was checking the length of the value using the following query, it showed me the length as 7

```
-- Check the length
select (Name), len(Name) AS TextLength
from [dbo].[RoutineMaintenanceTask]
where Name = 'RM004'
```

It is obvious that this name contains some characters before or after, but it is not a space.

Not only that, I examined the value through Visual Studio debugger and did not notice anything unusual.

[image]

Nevertheless, when I copy the value of the “Name” from SQL results pane and copy it to notepad++, with special characters on, I was able to see this.

[image]

Ultimately, I was able to fix this the issue by adding following code before the select statement

```
-- Remove the tail
UPDATE [dbo].[RoutineMaintenanceTask] SET Name = substring(Name,1,5);
```

I just need to know how I get to know what are the hidden characters in a case like this and how to eliminate it without using substring (Because in this case, it was easy because I knew the length).

PS- I understand that using the keyword of ‘name’ as a field of a table is not a good practise, but in this context there is nothing to do with that.

Comment: Special characters are only special if you aren't expecting them. It's really just a matter of putting controls and constraints in place to control the data being inserted. If all values in that column are exactly 5 characters, why is it not defined as a CHAR(5)? If I letters [A-Z] & numbers [0-9] are the only valid characters, then that should be enforced with a CHECK constraint and or an "instead of" trigger.

Comment: As far as detecting what's already there... WHERE t.Name NOT LIKE '%[^0-9a-Z]%'

Comment: maybe you should use `ASCII()` to examine what special character is that, before you `substring()` it. If not mistaken, notepad++ has a plug in that will show you the ascii char

Comment: @JasonA.Long, Squirrel,  Thank you so much for your effort. I wrote a query to reveal the unknown characters and it recognized the characters as Line feed & Carriage return. I got enlightened myself by your comments. You can see the query here. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qicbv7aNLSbzNYQEBILGfQnktpimRq-F

Comment: @KushanRandima - There's no reason to use a loop or cursor to itterate through the characters. See the answers section for a better option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was likely either char(9), char(10), or char(13) (tab,lf,cr; respectively).

You can read up on them here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/char-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

You can remove them using `REPLACE()`.

Such as:

```
DECLARE @VARIABLE VARCHAR(10)

SET @VARIABLE='RM004'+CHAR(10)+CHAR(10)

SELECT @VARIABLE, LEN(@VARIABLE)

SET @VARIABLE = REPLACE(@VARIABLE, CHAR(9),'')
SET @VARIABLE = REPLACE(@VARIABLE, CHAR(10),'')
SET @VARIABLE = REPLACE(@VARIABLE, CHAR(13),'')

SELECT @VARIABLE, LEN(@VARIABLE)
```

Comment: You are right. I just wrote a script to print ASCII values for each character of the 'Name' value. The extra characters are 13 and 10. Thank you so much for your consideration.

Comment: Please see the query I wrote - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qicbv7aNLSbzNYQEBILGfQnktpimRq-F

Comment: I am unable to click that as I am behind a firewall which blocks google drive, but glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(8000) = 'RM004
     ';

WITH 
    cte_n1 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (n)), 
    cte_n2 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n1 a CROSS JOIN cte_n1 b),
    cte_Tally (n) AS (
        SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(@string))
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
        FROM
            cte_n2 a CROSS JOIN cte_n2 b
        )
SELECT 
    position = t.n,
    char_value = SUBSTRING(@string, t.n, 1),
    ascii_value = ASCII(SUBSTRING(@string, t.n, 1))
FROM
    cte_Tally t;
```

[image]